# What's the meaning of 'experience' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://www.npr.org/2023/06/07/1180791069/apple-autocorrect-ducking) :

> The update also aims to make autocorrect better at fixing grammatical
> mistakes and predicting words or phrases as users type, as well as
> making dictation more accurate, Apple says.
>
> The new autocorrect will "improve the **experience** every time you
> type," Federighi said.

I looked up noun 'experience' in [the M-W dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experience) :

> 1a : direct observation of or participation in events as a basis of
> knowledge
>
> 2a : practical knowledge, skill, or practice derived from direct
> observation of or participation in events or in a particular activity

I think if the 'experience' is a user's(a typist's) experience, it means 1a and if it is the autocorrect's (=upgraded system's) experience, it means 2a because the autocorrect learns the pattern (=practical knowledge) from observation of a user's typing every time a user types.

Am I wrong?

Comment: "Am I wrong?" Yes. :p The word "experience" here has a different sense. It's saying that the typist will be happier / more satisfied when typing thanks to these changes. (It's not using "experience" in the sense of knowledge gained through doing something, but rather how the action is perceived in terms of pleasure/displeasure.)

Comment: @ralph.m Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure why you only quote 2 of the definitions - "3: something personally encountered, undergone, or lived through", seems more fitting, referring to what is encountered by the user.

Comment: Also see: [User Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience)

Comment: @StuartF That's it! User experience. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sense intended:
[Wiktionary *experience*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/experience)

1. **The effect upon the judgment or feelings produced by any event**, whether witnessed or participated in; **personal and direct impressions** as contrasted with description or fancies; personal acquaintance; **actual enjoyment or suffering**.
   *It was an experience he would not soon forget.*
   [emphasis added]

It refers to the user's experience: "every time **you** type."

Comment: Thank you very much.